# Output the difference in character XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, lxml

I have two variables $word1 and $word2  and the values are:

```
$word1 = 'America'
$word2 = 'American'
```

NOw using `XSLT` i have to compare both the variables and then output the difference in the character.

For example the output has to be 'n'. How could I do this in `XSLT 1.0`??

I found a function called `index-of-string` in XSLT 2.0!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean exactly by 'difference'. To check if `$word2` starts with `$word1` and return the remaining part you can simply do:

```
substring-after($word2,$word1)
```

that returns 'n' in you example.

If you need to check if `$word1` appears anywhere within `$word2` - and then return the parts of `$word2` before/after `$word1` you have to use a recursive template:

```
<xsl:template name="substring-before-after">
  <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
  <xsl:param name="str1"/>
  <xsl:param name="str2"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($str1)>=string-length($str2)">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring($str1,1,string-length($str2))=$str2">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix,substring($str1,string-length($str2)+1))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-after">
            <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="concat($prefix,substring($str1,1,1))"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="str1" select="substring($str1,2)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="str2" select="$str2"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

that you call like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="substring-before-after">
  <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="''"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="str1" select="$word2"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="str2" select="$word1"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

this return still 'n' in your example, and returns 'An' if `$word1 = 'merica' etc..

Note that this approach returns an empty string if the two strings are identical AND if the second string is not contained in the first one. You can modify this returning some kind of 'special' in the second case modifying the last `otherwise`:

```
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>[SPECIAl STRING]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
```